# Uninstalling django-tinymce. Import error when makemigrations

Tags: python, django, django-tinymce

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

I was not happy with TinyMCE extension in django and decided to switch to django-summernote. I first ran

```
pip uninstall django-tinymce
```

Removed all mentions of tinymce in the actual project.

Followed the instruction to install django-summernote. Upon completion I decided to run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

to apply new extension, but get an error:

```
File "/Users/rasulkireev/Sites/dj-pw/now/migrations/0006_auto_20190703_0134.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tinymce.models
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinymce'
```

I'm not sure why would Django care about what I did previously since I am simply asking to replace the editor. I can't run `python manage.py runserver` either.

I can't do anything before fixing this. I beg you guys, please help.

**Note: I would ideally want to keep the contents of my current database.**

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Not sure, that's why I'm commenting and not answering the question, but I think you can comment that line in the migration file `0006_auto_20190703_0134.py` to see If it helps. I've already edited migrations file before, but not sure about a import statement. Also make sure to comment the parts where this module is being used.

Comment: can you share **0006_auto_20190703_0134.py**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have removed all the mentions of tinymce from the models, admins and other files, you need to migrate using a special "flag":

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

I am not to clear on the backend of this method, but it works. You can read more about it the official Django website:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/

> This will make a new initial migration for your app. Now, run python
>   manage.py migrate --fake-initial, and Django will detect that you have
>   an initial migration and that the tables it wants to create already
>   exist, and will mark the migration as already applied. (Without the
>   migrate --fake-initial flag, the command would error out because the
>   tables it wants to create already exist.)
>
> Note that this only works given two things:
>
> 1. You have not changed your models since you made their tables. For
>      migrations to work, you must make the initial migration first and
>      then make changes, as Django compares changes against migration files, not the database.
> 2. You have not manually edited your database - Django won’t be able to detect that your database doesn’t match your models, you’ll just get errors when migrations try to modify those tables.